# Having Trouble to use material table component with material-ui v3, so is there any way to use material tale with material-ui ui v3?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i am using material table as data-table but it did't work with material-ui v3 as it has material-ui v4 as a peer dependency, so when i update my material-ui version from v3 to v4 it's working, here is the problem arise,

the project on which i am working has very large code base and have many components so i don't want to migrate material-ui from v3 to v4 so i tried some googling about this but can't find any answer,

**so is there any way that i can use material-table component with material-ui v3 or is there any that i can use both version in one project ?**

Comment: You could try installing an older version of material-table that used v3? 1.36.6 was the last one I think.

Comment: @dalmo3 thanks it's working